# Ansible conditional module arguments

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is it possible to only include module argument when a certain condition is valid, without duplicating the play?

Example:

I have a play that looks like the following:

```
  - name: Start Container
    docker:
      name: "{{containerName}}"
      state: reloaded
      command: "java -jar {{containerImage}}-{{containerJarVersion}}.jar"
```

I want to change the value of the command argument depending on if a condition is true of false? Currently, I have to duplicate the whole play and wrap it in a condition, which is horrible as only one argument is different.

Current solution:

```
  - name: Start Container Debug
    docker:
      name: "{{containerName}}"
      state: reloaded
      command: "java  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,address={{debugPort}} -jar {{containerImage}}-{{containerJarVersion}}.jar"
    when: ({{enableDebug}} == true)

  - name: Start Container
    docker:
      name: "{{containerName}}"
      state: reloaded
      command: "java -jar {{containerImage}}-{{containerJarVersion}}.jar"
    when: ({{enableDebug}} == false)
```

Comment: Sorry I might be getting this wrong.. What's the difference between the two tasks? They look the same thing to me.

Comment: Sorry copy and paste error, updated the code example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will still have to use a conditional somewhere (You want to do different things based on a condition in the end..:).

The only thing I can think of is avoid you writing your task twice ( causing all those annoying `skipped` ), you could do the following:

```
     # file: play.yml

     - include_vars: debug_vars.yml
        when: enableDebug == True

     - include_vars: prod_vars.yml
        when: enableDebug == False


     - name: Start Container
       docker:
          name: "{{containerName}}"
          state: reloaded
          command: "{{ start_container_command }}"



      # file: debug_vars.yml
        start_container_command: "java  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,address={{debugPort}} -jar {{containerImage}}-{{containerJarVersion}}.jar"

      # file: prod_vars.yml
        start_container_command: "java -jar {{containerImage}}-{{containerJarVersion}}.jar"
```

Answer (score 2):

(Now) You can use this inline conditional mechanism

```
start_container_command: "java {{'-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,address={{debugPort}}' if not enableDebug else '' }} -jar {{containerImage}}-{{containerJarVersion}}.jar"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
  - name: Start Container Debug
    docker:
      name: "{{containerName}}"
      state: reloaded
      command: "java  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,address={{debugPort}} -jar {{containerImage}}-{{containerJarVersion}}.jar"
    when: enableDebug # Will run when the value of  eanbleDebug is True

  - name: Start Container
    docker:
      name: "{{containerName}}"
      state: reloaded
      command: "java  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,address={{debugPort}} -jar {{containerImage}}-{{containerJarVersion}}.jar"
    when: not enableDebug # Will run when the value of  eanbleDebug is False
```

I am supposing the `eanbleDebug` will be like this:

```
eanbleDebug: True
or 
eanbleDebug: False
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: This is more or less exactly what I have? I was hoping there would be a solution that would mean I didn't have to duplicate the play...